# Confused between usage of Was or Were when referring to "number of push ups"

Tags: grammatical-number, subject-verb-agreement

> I want to say that on Wednesday the number of push ups **were/was** 20.

Is the above mentioned line correct?

Comment: Was. The verb refers to the word 'number', not 'push-ups'. 'number' is singular.

Answer (score 2):

The number of push-ups was 20. The number was 20. There were 20 push-ups.

Edit: The long version, for clarity--
 "The number of push-ups was 20" is the correct choice. The form of the verb (were/was, infinitive "to be") is determined by "number" in this case. This can be tested by removing "of push-ups" from the sentence, which yields the grammatically correct sentence, "The number was 20." An example of a sentence that uses "were" correctly is, "On Wednesday, there were 20 push-ups."

Comment: Kindly improve your answer. The OP wants to know that why we would use 'was' or 'were'.